# Copy data from double data type pointer to char array in c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have a double data type pointer and size is about 512KB. I am trying to copy the data present in double data type pointer to char array.

My code looks as shown below:

```
double *DDR = (double *)0x90000000;
char array[524288];
```

How to copy the data present in `DDR` pointer to char array.

Comment: `memcpy(array, DDR, some_size)`?

Comment: A first approach would be using `memcpy`. Does the memory at that address have some special restictions, e.g. accessing a `double` at once instead of using byte access?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details about your use case. What is the purpose to copy the `double` type data to a `char` array?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to make a hard copy of 512kb though? Just to get a different representation? If so, use a union.

Comment: @ram You should update your question to clarify your use case, even if you already accepted an answer. Reasons: 1. Someone might be able to give a better answer. 2. The question with its answer(s) might be more useful for other users who are searching for a solution for a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unless special restrictions apply to the memory area referred to by the absolute address `0x90000000`, you can just use `memcpy`:

```
#include <string.h>

   ...
   double *DDR = (double *)0x90000000;
   char array[524288];
   memcpy(array, DDR, sizeof(array));
   ...
```

Alternately, you can use a loop:

```
   double *DDR = (double *)0x90000000;
   char array[524288];
   char *p = (char *)DDR;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof array; i++) {
       array[i] = p[i];
   }
```

The compiler might actually generate the same code for both approaches.

Comment: Casting the `char` pointer (`array`) to a `double` pointer (`dp`) is undefined behavior. You should do it the other way round.

Comment: That loop is plain wrong. Something like `char* byteptr = (char*)DDR; for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof array; i++) { array[i] = byteptr[i]; }` would have been acceptable (but potentially more inefficient than memcpy).

Comment: @Bodo: silly me! of course undefined behavior because `array` might not be properly aligned, among other issues.

Comment: @Lundin: you are absolutely right! answer updated.